# Android 4.2 "Partition...has a different major than its disk!" error in logcat

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, encryption, partitions

I'm using a Samsung i9100 running Android 4.2.2 via sentinelrom_v4_75_i9100.  No changes to the kernel outside what came with that ROM.

I've tried encrypting a number of different 4.2.2 ROMs and always after a few reboots the sdcard0 doesn't mount.

Before encrypting again (and presumably having the same problem) I'm trying to trouble shoot the issue ahead of time.

Logcat is spitting out the following errors.

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
06-14 14:53:58.775 I/Vold    (1842): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up
06-14 14:53:58.785 D/Vold    (1842): Volume sdcard0 state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
06-14 14:53:58.785 D/Vold    (1842): Volume sdcard1 state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
06-14 14:53:58.785 D/Vold    (1842): Volume usbdisk0 state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
06-14 14:53:58.795 I/Netd    (1843): Netd 1.0 starting
06-14 14:53:58.800 W/InterfaceController(1843): Error (Symbol not found: ) while searching for the interface command fini function
06-14 14:53:58.805 D/Vold    (1842): Volume sdcard0 state changing 0 (No-Media) -> 2 (Pending)
06-14 14:53:58.805 D/DirectVolume(1842): DirectVolume::handlePartitionAdded -> MAJOR 179, MINOR 1, PARTN 1
06-14 14:53:58.805 D/DirectVolume(1842): DirectVolume::handlePartitionAdded -> MAJOR 179, MINOR 2, PARTN 2
06-14 14:53:58.810 D/DirectVolume(1842): DirectVolume::handlePartitionAdded -> MAJOR 179, MINOR 3, PARTN 3
06-14 14:53:58.810 D/DirectVolume(1842): DirectVolume::handlePartitionAdded -> MAJOR 179, MINOR 4, PARTN 4
06-14 14:53:58.810 D/DirectVolume(1842): DirectVolume::handlePartitionAdded -> MAJOR 179, MINOR 5, PARTN 5
06-14 14:53:58.825 D/DirectVolume(1842): DirectVolume::handlePartitionAdded -> MAJOR 179, MINOR 6, PARTN 6
06-14 14:53:58.825 D/DirectVolume(1842): DirectVolume::handlePartitionAdded -> MAJOR 179, MINOR 7, PARTN 7
06-14 14:53:58.825 D/Vold    (1842): Volume sdcard0 state changing 2 (Pending) -> 1 (Idle-Unmounted)
06-14 14:53:58.825 D/DirectVolume(1842): DirectVolume::handlePartitionAdded -> MAJOR 259, MINOR 0, PARTN 8
06-14 14:53:58.825 E/DirectVolume(1842): Partition '/devices/platform/dw_mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p8' has a different major than its disk!
06-14 14:53:58.825 W/Vold    (1842): Duplicate state (1)
06-14 14:53:58.825 D/DirectVolume(1842): DirectVolume::handlePartitionAdded -> MAJOR 259, MINOR 1, PARTN 9
06-14 14:53:58.825 E/DirectVolume(1842): Partition '/devices/platform/dw_mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p9' has a different major than its disk!
06-14 14:53:58.825 W/Vold    (1842): Duplicate state (1)
06-14 14:53:58.825 D/DirectVolume(1842): DirectVolume::handlePartitionAdded -> MAJOR 259, MINOR 2, PARTN 10
06-14 14:53:58.825 E/DirectVolume(1842): Partition '/devices/platform/dw_mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p10' has a different major than its disk!
06-14 14:53:58.825 W/Vold    (1842): Duplicate state (1)
06-14 14:53:58.825 D/DirectVolume(1842): DirectVolume::handlePartitionAdded -> MAJOR 259, MINOR 3, PARTN 11
06-14 14:53:58.825 E/DirectVolume(1842): Partition '/devices/platform/dw_mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p11' has a different major than its disk!
06-14 14:53:58.825 W/Vold    (1842): Duplicate state (1)
06-14 14:53:58.830 D/DirectVolume(1842): DirectVolume::handlePartitionAdded -> MAJOR 259, MINOR 4, PARTN 12
06-14 14:53:58.830 E/DirectVolume(1842): Partition '/devices/platform/dw_mmc/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p12' has a different major than its disk!
06-14 14:53:58.830 W/Vold    (1842): Duplicate state (1)
06-14 14:53:58.830 D/Vold    (1842): Volume sdcard1 state changing 0 (No-Media) -> 2 (Pending)
06-14 14:53:58.830 D/DirectVolume(1842): DirectVolume::handlePartitionAdded -> MAJOR 179, MINOR 9, PARTN 1
06-14 14:53:58.830 D/Vold    (1842): Volume sdcard1 state changing 2 (Pending) -> 1 (Idle-Unmounted)
```

Is there a way I can correct this?
I flashed I9100XWLSN_I9100XXMS2_I9100OXXLS8_HOME.tar.md5 as my clean ROM before flashing this ROM.  Is there a better stock rom to clean up the device before flashing a custom rom?

Thanks for your time.
Ed